# How to prove the infinite product expression of this Jacobian elliptic $\operatorname{sn}$ function?

Tags: special-functions, infinite-product, elliptic-functions

How to prove the following infinite product expression?

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{sn}(x,k)=\tanh \left(\frac{\pi\,\!x}{2 K(k')}\right)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty\,}\frac{ \tanh \left(\frac{\pi\left(2K(k) n-x\right)}{2K(k')}\right) \tanh \left(\frac{\pi  \left(2K(k) n+x\right)}{2K(k')}
\right)}
{\tanh^2\left(\frac{\pi\,\!K(k)}{K(k')}\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}
\end{align*}

Are there similar infinite product expressions for other Jacobian elliptic functions?

---

```
NumberForm[JacobiSN[0.01, 0.2^2], 15]
NumberForm[
 Tanh[(\[Pi]*x)/(2 EllipticK[1 - k^2])]*
   NProduct[(
     Tanh[(\[Pi] (2 EllipticK[k^2] n - x))/(
       2 EllipticK[1 - k^2])] Tanh[(\[Pi] (2 EllipticK[k^2] n + x))/(
       2 EllipticK[1 - k^2])])/
     Tanh[(\[Pi]*EllipticK[k^2])/
        EllipticK[1 - k^2]*(n - 1/2)]^2 /. {k -> 0.2, x -> 0.01}, {n, 
     1, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> 15] /. {k -> 0.2, x -> 0.01}, 15]
```

Output

```
0.009999826667967988 + 0.0*I
0.00999982666796799
```

It is important to note that in Mathematica's default function, the second parameter of the Jacobian elliptic function sn is $m=k^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's note the standard product formulas
\begin{align}
\text{sn}(u, k) &= \dfrac{2q^{1/4}}{\sqrt{k}}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi u}{2K}\right)\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1 - 2q^{2n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u}{K}\right) + q^{4n}}{1 - 2q^{2n - 1}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u}{K}\right) + q^{4n - 2}}\tag{1}\\
\text{cn}(u, k) &=\dfrac{2q^{1/4}\sqrt{k'}}{\sqrt{k}}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u}{2K}\right)\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1 + 2q^{2n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u}{K}\right) + q^{4n}}{1 - 2q^{2n - 1}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u}{K}\right) + q^{4n - 2}}\tag{2}
\end{align} where $q=\exp(-\pi K'/K) $.

From these we get the product for $\text{sc} (u, k) $ as $$\text{sc} (u, k) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k'}}\tan\left(\frac{\pi u} {2K}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1-2q^{2n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u} {K} \right) +q^{4n}}{1+2q^{2n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi u} {K} \right) +q^{4n}}\tag{3}$$ Let's further observe Jacobi imaginary transformation $$\text{sn} (u, k) =-i\, \text{sc} (iu, k') $$ and then using $(3)$ we have the following product for $\text{sn} (u, k) $ $$\text{sn} (u, k) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi u} {2K'}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1-2q'^{2n}\cosh\left(\dfrac{\pi u} {K'} \right) +q'^{4n}}{1+2q'^{2n}\cosh\left(\dfrac{\pi u} {K'} \right) +q'^{4n}}$$ where $q'=\exp(-\pi K/K') $.

Next we need to observe that $$\frac{ 1-q'^{2n}\cosh(\pi u/K') +q'^{4n}}{1+q'^{2n}\cosh(\pi u/K') +q'^{4n}}=\frac{1-q'^{2n}\exp(-\pi u/K')}{1+q'^{2n}\exp(-\pi u/K')}\cdot \frac{1-q'^{2n}\exp(\pi u/K')} {1+q'^{2n}\exp(\pi u/K')} $$ and the right hand side can be written as $$\tanh\left(\frac{n\pi K} {K'} - \frac{\pi u} {2K'}\right)\tanh\left(\frac{n\pi K} {K'} +\frac{\pi u} {2K'}\right)$$ and hence we have the expansion $$\text{sn} (u, k) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi u} {2K'}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{n\pi K} {K'} - \frac{\pi u} {2K'}\right)\tanh\left(\frac{n\pi K} {K'} +\frac{\pi u} {2K'}\right)\tag{4}$$ Further note that we have the product expansion $$k'=\frac{\vartheta_4^2(q)}{\vartheta_3^2(q)}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2n-1}}\right)^4$$ which leads to $$\sqrt{k} =\frac{\vartheta_4(q')}{\vartheta_3(q')}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-q'^{2n-1}}{1+q'^{2n-1}}\right)^2=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\tanh^2\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi K}{2K'}\right)\tag{5}$$ Using $(4),(5)$ we get the desired product expansion in question.

---

For each elliptic function of the arguments $u, k$ we can apply Jacobi imaginary transformation and write it as a function of arguments $iu, k'$ and use their standard product representations to get expansions in terms of $\pi u/K'$.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is

> How to prove the following infinite product expression?
> \begin{align*}
> \operatorname{sn}(x,k)=\tanh \left(\frac{\pi\,\!x}{2 K(k')}\right)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty\,}\frac{ \tanh \left(\frac{\pi\left(2K(k) n-x\right)}{2K(k')}\right) \tanh \left(\frac{\pi  \left(2K(k) n+x\right)}{2K(k')}
> \right)}
> {\tanh^2\left(\frac{\pi\,\!K(k)}{K(k')}\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}
> \end{align*}

I don't know of any reference to such an expansion
using hypberbolic tangent. The closest using just
sine and cosine is from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik,
*Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, section
$\bf{8.146.23}$ or other sources (where
$\,q=e^{-\pi K(k')/K(k)}$)

$$ \text{sn} u = \frac{2\sqrt[4]{q}}{\sqrt{k}}
\sin \frac{\pi u}{2K(k)} \prod_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{1-2q^{2n}\cos \frac{\pi u}{K(k)}+q^{4n}}
{1-2q^{2n-1}\cos \frac{\pi u}{K(k)}+q^{4n-2}}.
$$

The key idea is that elliptic functions are doubly
periodic with equal number of zeros and poles (up
to multiplicity) in a period parallelogram. For the
elliptic function $\,\text{sn}(z|m)\,$ there are two
zeros at $\,z=0\,$ and $\,z=2K(m)\,$ and two poles
at $\,z=iK'(m)\,$ and $\,z=2K(m)+iK'(m).\,$
The two periods are $\,4K(m)\,$ and $\,2iK'(m).\,$
The zeros and poles alternate along vertical lines
of the period rectangles. As $\,m\to 1^{-}\,$ the
real period $\,4K(m)\to\infty\,$ and
$\,\text{sn}(z|m)\to \tanh(z).\,$ The function
$\,\tanh(z)\,$ has zeros at $\,n\pi i\,$ and poles
at $\,(n-\frac12)\pi i.\,$ Thus, It has an infinite
product expansion as

$$ \tanh(z) = z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^2 + (n\pi)^2}
{z^2 + ((n-1/2)\pi)^2}\left(\frac{n}{n-1/2}\right)^{-2}.
\tag1 $$

Thus, to a first approximation

$$ \text{sn}(z) := \text{sn}(z|m) \approx \tanh
\left(\frac{z\,\pi}{2K'(m)}\right) \tag2 $$

and missing the rest of its zeros and poles.

Define the function

$$
T(z) := T(z|m) = \tanh\left(\frac{z\,\pi K(m)}{2K'(m)}\right). \tag3 $$

The infinite product expansion of sn is

$$ \text{sn}(zK(m)) = T(z)\prod_{n=1}^\infty
 \frac{T(2n-z)T(2n+z)}{T(2n-1)^2}. \tag4 $$

A quick check using Wolfram `Mathematica`:

```
z = 13/100; m = 21/100; M = 7; DP = 15;
K0 = EllipticK[m]; K1 = EllipticK[1-m];
T[z_] := Tanh[z*Pi/2*K0/K1];
N[{JacobiSN[z*K0, m], T[z]*Product[
   T[2*n - z]*T[2*n + z] /
   T[2*n - 1]^2, {n, 1, M}]}, DP] //NumberForm
(* {0.214382745916949, 0.214382745916948} *)
```

Note that in this expansion, the zeros and
poles match which implies the two sides of
the equation differ only by a constant factor.
I don't yet have a proof that
the constant factor is $1$ or of the identity

$$ k^{1/4} = m^{1/8} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty T(2n-1). \tag5 $$

The second question is

> Are there similar infinite product expressions for other Jacobian elliptic functions?

The answer is yes. It is known that
$$ \text{sc}(z,k) = -i\,\text{sn}(i\,z,k'), \quad
\tanh(z) = -i\,\tan(i\,z) \tag6 $$

which means that a slightly modified version of the
infinite product expansion for sn becomes the infinite
product expansion for sc using tan instead of tanh.

I think there may be an expansion for $\text{sd}(z,k)$
but I will have to do some work for that.

Comment: The identity $(5)$ is true. If we put $q'=\exp(-\pi K/K') $ then the infinite product equals $\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q'^{2n-1})/(1+q'^{2n-1})$. The product with $q'$ replaced by $q$ equals the ratio of Ramanujan class invariants $g/G=k'^{1/4}$. Thus for $q'$ the product equals $k^{1/4}$.

Comment: Further one can note that $\text{sn} (u, k) =-i\, \text{sc} (iu, k') $ and $\tanh x=-i\tan ix$ and get desired product.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_in_terms_of_Jacobi_theta_functions gives expressions for the Jacobi elliptic functions as products of theta functions, and expressions for the theta functions as infinite products. E.g.,
$$
{\rm cn}(u;\,k)={\theta_{01}(q)\theta_{11}(\zeta;\,q)\over\theta_{11}(q)\theta_{01}(\zeta;\,q)}
$$
where
$$
\theta_{01}(v;\,w)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-w^{2n})(1-2\cos(2v)w^{2n-1}+w^{4n-2})
$$
and $\theta_{01}(q)=\theta_{01}(0;\ q)$, and some equally complicated formula for $\theta_{11}$.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You have no mention of $\tanh(.)$ or $K(k')$ as in the infinite product expression and no proof.

Comment: @Somos, the question I am answering is, "Are there similar infinite product expressions for other Jacobian elliptic functions?" I'll grant you that what I found isn't all that similar to what OP has, but in any event it is an infinite product for another Jacobi elliptic function. If OP doesn't like it, OP won't vote for it, and won't accept it, and I won't complain. If you have a better answer, I encourage you to post it.